# Users table does not exist

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have made a module that use `Users` table of DNN.
But today I get wired error that `Users` table does not exist.
When I looked in database I saw that `Users` table name is actually `dbo_Users`.
I thought that DNN `Users` table always have the same name but it seams it is not.
What is the reason that dnn added that prefix to table (all DNN tables) and how can I know if table has that prefix?

Comment: is it an underscore or a dot? dbo.Users would indicate the users table within the dbo schema.

Comment: No it's underscore not schema. For the first time I see that default dnn tables has prefix tbl_TableName.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DotNetNuke allows setting up a site with an "[object qualifier](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/objectQualifier.aspx)" for the database (as well as a custom schema/database owner).  This enables a little better security, and gives the potential to host multiple applications within the same database while avoiding naming conflicts.  Neither of those reasons are very good, and few make use of the feature, but you still run into it now and then.

You can use `DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Config.GetObjectQualifer()` to get the object qualifier of the current site.

In any scripts that you run as part of a package's installation, DNN will automatically replace `{databaseOwner}` and `{objectQualifier}` tokens with the correct value.

If you use [Entity Framework](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/brandonhaynes/2009/09/08/dotnetnuke-entity-framework-model-adapter/) or [LINQ to SQL](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/brandonhaynes/2008/10/14/using-the-linq-to-sql-adapter-in-a-dotnetnuke-module/), there are model adapters which have been put together by Brandon Haynes which automatically take these into account.

Comment: I am not at the pc so I can't test at the moment. So as I understand `GetObjectQualifer()` should return `dbo_` (in my case)? So when I build query I can use something like `"select * from " + GetObjectQualifer() + "Users"`.

Comment: I would also add that the db qualifier is stored in the web.config file for reference, so you can quickly look it up there.  However, you can't change it in the web.config, because it is used in the original installation of the site.